# Toggle New Relic monitoring for workers on Heroku

Tags: heroku, newrelic

Is there a way to selectively enable/disable New Relic for workers on Heroku? New Relic is really useful for our web app, but we cannot really afford to have it monitor our workers all the time.

Comment: You could set "agent_enabled: false" in your newrelic.yml file for the environment under which your background workers run. How are you running your workers? Resque, etc.?

(New Relic on Heroku is free with a Standard plan, so I guess you've got Pro.)

Answer (score 0):

config/newrelic.yml is processed with ERB so you can do something like this in it:

```
monitor_mode: <%= ...some logic to return true or false... %>
```

Note that "monitor_mode" is specified multiple times in config/newrelic.yml so make sure you update the appropriate spot (look at the bottom of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested yet, but I think this is the approach:

```
# Procfile

workerA: env NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=$WORKER_A_NEW_RELIC_AGENT bin/your_process
```

Then, to enable:

```
heroku config:set WORKER_A_NEW_RELIC_AGENT=true
heroku restart
```

Answer (score -1):

You could provision and de-provision the add-on on Heroku as needed. Add-on charges are pro-rated, so you'll only be billed for the actual time that the add-on is provisioned to your app.

If you have a lot of dynos, you might also want to get in touch with New Relic to see if they can help you out with a discount or something.

Comment: Right, but we want continual web monitoring and only occasional worker monitoring--that's the concern :/

Comment: @RonGejman that wouldn't be possible without partitioning out the web and background workers to separate apps, I think.